# how to reset uploadcare widget to original state after the file upload is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, uploadcare

I am using [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) widget to upload profile images in an nodejs app.
In Uploadcare widget once user is done uploading a single file, I want to go back to original widget state so the user can choose another image to replace the previous one.

```
widget.onUploadComplete(function(info) {
    // assign image to image tag
    $('#avatar').attr('src', info.cdnUrl);

    // reset the widget to user can see the the "choose image" button again. 
    widget.value();
}
```

However the widget.value() doesn't seem to do anything although that is suggested on [issue](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget/issues/213) on uploadcare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`widget.value` is getter/setter method, so `widget.value()` will just return current value.

Use `widget.value(null)` to reset.

You can find more in Uploadcare JS API [documentation](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/javascript_api/#widget).

p.s.: thanks for the tip, I have improved an answer in github issue.

Comment: thanks, it did work. However I also manage to get the same results with       $('.uploadcare-widget-button-remove').click();